# load articles ajaxly in joomla

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, joomla, mootools

Is there anyway to load content body by click on its title ajaxly in the same page?
should I make changes in template or use an extra extension?

also just can use javascript plugins and not changing them unless they have a specific manual for the certain plugin.

Regards...

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this plugin: 
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/structure-a-navigation/site-navigation/6396

Cheers,

Gerlof

Comment: Thanks alot,
It just navigate between whole pages and not singles content. 
Is there a more similar extension to achieve my purpose ? 

Regards ...